# Checking checked in group radio buttons - validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have:

```
<div class="group">
   <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1">a
   <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2">b
</div>
<div class="group">
   <input type="radio" name="two" value="3">a
   <input type="radio" name="two" value="4">b
</div>
<div class="group">
   <input type="radio" name="aaa" value="5">a
   <input type="radio" name="aaa" value="6">b
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jz84u/2/

How can i check if minimum one group is checked in this example? If no then should be alert('error').
I would like use jQuery.

```
$(".group").each(function(){

})
```

but how can i check this? For my example should be return error - any input is checked, but if i have:

```
<div class="group">
   <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1">a
   <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2">b
</div>
<div class="group">
   <input type="radio" name="two" value="3">a
   <input type="radio" name="two" value="4" checked="checked">b
</div>
<div class="group">
   <input type="radio" name="aaa" value="5">a
   <input type="radio" name="aaa" value="6">b
</div>
```

for this example is ok - input in second group is checked.

How can i validate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this fit your needs?

```
   var n = $(".group input:checked").length;

   if(n>0){do something}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below it will work...

Add a button

```
<input type="button" value="check" id="btnCheck">

<div class="group">
   <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1">a
   <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2">b
</div>
<div class="group">
   <input type="radio" name="two" value="3">a
   <input type="radio" name="two" value="4">b
</div>
<div class="group">
   <input type="radio" name="aaa" value="5">a
   <input type="radio" name="aaa" value="6">b
</div>
```

write a jquery like below

```
$("#btnCheck").click(function() {

   if($(".group input:radio:checked").val())
       alert("checked");
    else
    alert("Nothing checked");   

});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jz84u/6/